# Assert method call without stub?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking, ruby-mocha

I would like to assert that a particular method was called, but I don't want to mock/stub the method - I want to include that code in the test as well.

For example, in Ruby, something like:

```
def bar()
  #stuff I want to test
end

def foo()
  if condition
    bar()
  end

  #more stuff I want to test
end

# The test:

foo()
assert_called :bar
```

Does anyone have a suggestion (or a better way to go about it)?  My actual code is quite a bit more complex, so please don't take the simplicity of the example into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
require 'set'

class Class
  def instrument
    self.instance_methods.each do |m|
      old = method(m)
      define_method(m) do |*a,&b|
        @__called__ ||= Set.new
        @__called__ << m
        old.bind(self).call(*a,&b)
      end
    end
  end
end

class Object
  def assert_called(method)
    if not (@__called__ && @__called__.include?(method))
      # You will have to figure out how to make this equivalent to a failing
      #   assertion for your favorite test framework
      raise "Assertion failed! #{method} has not been called"
    end
  end
end
```

Then after defining your classes, but before running tests:

```
FooClass.instrument
```

Note that I haven't tested this code yet!

Comment: Daniel, are you familiar enough with Ruby metaprogramming to take the idea which I am demonstrating and make it reality?

Comment: I get the gist of it - that is definitely the Ruby approach :-)

I will probably do it more explicitly for the methods I actually test:

    old = method(:foo)
    define_method(:foo) do
    ...
    end

Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful! Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

It's really a good way to make it two test cases, one would call `foo()` and check if `bar()` is called and another to check if `bar()` does it's thing well. When you're testing `foo()`, you should know what `bar()` should return.